# Как имитировать перетаскивание мышью java?

Tags: java

Тема была закрыта, я отредактировал её. Вот в чем вопрос. Нужно сыметировать нажатие-перетаскивание-отжатие по координатам ( начальная позиция: нажатие ) - перетаскивание - ( конечная позиция: отпускание ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void drag(int xFrom , int yFrom,int xTo, int yTo) throws AWTException, InterruptedException{
    Robot bot = new Robot();

    bot.mouseMove(xFrom, yFrom); // двигаем мышку на начальные координаты
    bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK); 

    bot.mouseMove(xTo, yTo); // тащим на конечную
    bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
}
```